# Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

We are testing our website using google page speed. The link is: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.efacility.in%2F

In this section 'Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers' we are getting errors for the following.

1. Array.prototype.filter
2. Date.now
3. @babel/plugin-transform-classes

For 1 we noted that we need to use filter method as in this [link](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-use-javascript-array-prototype-filter-filter-explained-with-examples/14289). Please suggest how to provide the fix for the issues in 2 and 3.

Thanks

Comment: hmm i guess your babel is configurated to support internet explorer 8. filter works since IE 9. you should increase the support to atlest IE11. it would be good to tell us what techstack you use for your project like: react, vue, angular, nuxt, i dont know something different or non of them?

Comment: Hi, This website is using WordPress (PHP and MySQL). This is using Adada theme (https://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226)